# WPF: Binding fill & background brush to property in backing CS

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, dependencies

I have made a `usercontrol` which represents an Icon which I want to be able to use throughout my project.

I want to be able to have a property `IconColour` which I can use to change the colour of my Icon to different colours in different situations, while still using the same single `usercontrol` throughout the project.

In the case of my icon, there are parts which I want to be coloured as per the property, and some which should remain the same colour regardless of the brush used. Some parts may/may not have masking, some parts may be animated etc.

My problem is that regardless of the brush that I use on my `IconColour` property, the Icon is rendered transparent (presumably using the default brush because something isn't working properly).

I want to know how I can correctly bind my `IconColour` property to the `Brush` property of the `Polygon` below, so that I can set the `IconColour` to a brush of my choosing inline wherever the usercontrol is referenced.

---

#### Snippet from the Icon User Control

```
<UserControl>
...
<DrawingGroup Transform="1,0,0,1,227,21">
    <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding IconBrush}">
        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M46,51L46,51 46,23 68.4,37z" FillRule="EvenOdd" />
        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
    </GeometryDrawing>
</DrawingGroup>
...
</UserControl>
```

#### Backing C# for Icon User Control

```
namespace Style.Images.Icons.Playback.PlaybackPanelIcons
{
    public partial class PlayIcon
    {
        public Brush IconBrush
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(IconBrushProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IconBrushProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IconBrushProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IconBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(PlayIcon), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255,0,255)), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIconBrushChanged)));
        public PlayIcon()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IconBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(240, 255, 5));
        }

        private static void OnIconBrushChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            PlayIcon icon = sender as PlayIcon;
            icon.IconBrush = (Brush) args.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Snippet from where the Icon User Control is used

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel>
        <Icons:PlayIcon IconBrush="Green" Width="28" Height="28" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: `OnIconBrushChanged` callback doesn't do anything useful. It can be removed. `"{Binding IconBrush}"`  tries to bind to DataContext, which is wrong. you need to use `RelativeSource` or give Name to UC and use `ElementName` in Binding

Comment: @ASh thank you, you are correct. I shall amend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding IconBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
```

It should bind the `Brush` property of the `GeometryDrawing` to the `IconBrush` property of the parent `UserControl`.

Comment: Amazing @mm8, this is exactly the answer I needed! Many thanks :)